# Show time in message blocks

Tags: android, android-layout

I have message blocks.I want to show time right bottom of the message.This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/blocks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mes7"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:clickable="false">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:text="Test Message"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="19:40"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no problem with short messages but when message prolonged date is not showing.Here you can see:

[image]

And one more thing:I want to do margin from left edge but I can't.

How can I do these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap a `LinearLayout` around each one of your `TextViews`, so you can use `andorid:gravity` attribute in the `TextViews` accuratly. Define a width weight value to each one of your `LinearLayouts`, so your time is always showing, no matter how many lines the text message has. For that you have to use `android:weightSum` attribute in the parent layout (the root `LinearLayout`) ,set the `android:layout_width` values of your `LinearLayouts` to `0dp` and for last applying the percentage of width space in each one of the `LinearLayouts`, using `android:layout_weight` attribute. This will assure that your width values are always constant and relative to the device screen width.

Try it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Test Message is this it has to be big to you can test it test here"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:clickable="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="19:40"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Update:I found the problem.I think problem is "match_parent" we need to use "wrap_content" but when we use wrap_content time is not showing.If we use "match_parent" result: http://prntscr.com/4uqrwk

Comment: Update again:This was my fault.I was using layout params.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting a weight on the date:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/date"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:text="19:40"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:weight="1" />
```

Then you may or may not need to set the message width to fill:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/messageBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
android:text="Test Message"
android:typeface="sans"
android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has 
  layout_width="match_parent"
 - This LinearLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view I am getting this.

Comment: Your linearlayout 'blocks' doesn't specify a orientation. Not entirely sure what that layout is supposed to do.

Comment: add `android:orientation="horizontal"`